# I have a with JMS - ActiveMQ using http and https protocols

Tags: java, activemq-classic

My Producer:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Producer {
    //127.0.0.1 loop back to localhost
private static String url="http://127.0.0.1:61616";
private static String subject="DemoQueue4";

public static void main(String[] args)throws JMSException {
        ConnectionFactory cf=null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {

        // getting jms connection from the server and starting it.
            System.out.println("Please wait connecting...");
        cf=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        con=cf.createConnection();
        System.out.println("Successfully Connected \n");

        System.out.println("Please wait creating session...");
        Session s=con.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);    
        System.out.println("Session created \n");

        System.out.println("Please wait Creating Queue...");
        // create queue
        Destination d;
        d=s.createQueue(subject);
        System.out.println("Queue created \n");

        System.out.println("Please wait Creating Producer...");
        // create producer/sender
        MessageProducer mp;
        mp=s.createProducer(d);
        System.out.println("Producer created \n");

        System.out.println("Please wait Connection Starting...");
        con.start();
        System.out.println("Connection Started \n");

        System.out.println("Please wait Creating TextMessage..");
        // We will send a small text message saying 'Hello' in Japanese
        TextMessage message = s.createTextMessage("Hi How are you!");
        System.out.println("TextMessage Created \n");

        System.out.println("Please wait TextMessage Sending...");
        // Here we are sending the message!
        mp.send(message);
        System.out.println("TextMessage Sent '" + message.getText() + "'");
        System.out.println("Success");          

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(con!=null){
                con.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
/**i am trying to insert the text message to queue but it is not inserting**/
```

My Broker Config - activemq.xml:

```
/**this is my config file of activemq.xml**/

<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Allows log searching in hawtio console -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="org.fusesource.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->

            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="http://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>




     <!-- 
     <transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>

     <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/> -->
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>


Activemq version 5.9
jdk 1.8
eclipseIDE

jars:

activemq-all.jar
httpclient.jar
httpcore.jar
commonslogging-1.2.jar
com.thoughtworks.xstream.jar
xmlpull-xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
```

While running getting error `mp.send(message)` its a general simple example which you can also copy paste in your environment

```
Please wait connecting...
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Successfully Connected 

Please wait creating session...
Session created 

Please wait Creating Queue...
Queue created 

Please wait Creating Producer...
Producer created 

Please wait Connection Starting...
Connection Started 

Please wait Creating TextMessage..
TextMessage Created 

Please wait TextMessage Sending...
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not post command: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:WSTIN0128-50902-1472648010012-2:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:WSTIN0128-50902-1472648010012-2:1:1:1, destination = queue://DemoQueue4, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1472648011069, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@67d48005, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = Diyotta-http!} due to: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1423)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1333)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1811)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:289)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:224)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.send(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:241)
    at com.kumar.jmsproducer.Producer.main(Producer.java:57)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not post command: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:WSTIN0128-50902-1472648010012-2:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:WSTIN0128-50902-1472648010012-2:1:1:1, destination = queue://DemoQueue4, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1472648011069, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@67d48005, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = Diyotta-http!} due to: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.oneway(HttpClientTransport.java:138)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:286)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1394)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:116)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.oneway(HttpClientTransport.java:125)
    ... 12 more
```

### About ActiveMQ

The HTTP and HTTPS transports are used to tunnel over HTTP or HTTPS using XML payloads. This allows the ActiveMQ client and broker to tunnel over HTTP avoiding any firewall issues.

If the client is not JMS you might want to look at REST or Ajax support instead.
Note that the HTTP Transport is located in the `activemq-optional` jar.

ActiveMQ uses a combination of Jetty's Server and `SslSocketConnector` objects to communicate via the HTTPS transport. When using HTTPS, improper configuration of the corresponding SSL certificates and/or keys may very well lead to the Jetty infinite loop problem described in this nabble thread. A good reference on creating and configuring keys and certificates can be found here.

---

```
BrokerStartup.java

package com.kumar.httpsprotocol;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector;

public class BrokerStartup {

    private static final String KEYSTORE = "i:/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/broker.ks";
    private static final String TRUST_KEYSTORE = "i:/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/broker.ts";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "123456";

    static BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

    public static void startBorker(String host,String port) throws Exception{

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", KEYSTORE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", PASSWORD);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", TRUST_KEYSTORE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", PASSWORD);

        TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
        connector.setUri(new URI("https://"+host+":"+port));
        broker.addConnector(connector);
        broker.start();
        System.out.println("Broker Started.."+broker.getBrokerName());

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            startBorker("HostName","61616");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client Code: (Producer.java)

package com.kumar.httpsprotocol;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Producer {

    private static final String KEYSTORE = "i:/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/broker.ks";
    private static final String TRUSTSTORE = "i:/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/client.ts";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "123456";    

    public static void main(String[] args)throws JMSException {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", KEYSTORE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", PASSWORD);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", TRUSTSTORE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", PASSWORD);

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf=null;
        Connection con = null;

        try {

            System.out.println("Please wait connecting...");
            cf=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("https://HostName:61617");
            con=cf.createConnection();

            /*cf.setTrustStore("I:/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/client.ts");
            cf.setTrustStorePassword("123456");*/

            System.out.println("Successfully Connected \n");
            Session s=con.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);    
            System.out.println("Session created \n");
            Destination d=s.createQueue("DemoQueue7");
            MessageProducer mp=s.createProducer(d);
            con.start();
            System.out.println("Please wait Creating TextMessage..");
            TextMessage message = s.createTextMessage("Recieved from Kumar HTTPS Protocol!");
            System.out.println("TextMessage Created \n");
            System.out.println("Please wait TextMessage Sending...");
            mp.send(message);
            System.out.println("TextMessage Sent '" + message.getText() + "'");

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(con!=null){
                con.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

activemq.xml

```
 <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="https://HostName:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

### ERROR: while starting Broker

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslConnector.getSslContextFactory()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory;
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.SecureSocketConnectorFactory.createConnector(SecureSocketConnectorFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.https.HttpsTransportServer.doStart(HttpsTransportServer.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.start(TransportConnector.java:243)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:2501)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:2415)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:666)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:632)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:568)
    at com.kumar.httpsprotocol.BrokerStartup.startBorker(BrokerStartup.java:26)
    at com.kumar.httpsprotocol.BrokerStartup.main(BrokerStartup.java:33)
```

Comment: Confusing - it looks like you're answering your own question with that last paragraph.

Comment: defaultly broker is accepting tcp protocol but i am trying it with http and https i tried with http which working upto creating Textmessage i want to send textmessage to queue(activemq) but it is not executing... i m getting socket timeout exception

Comment: I would say HTTP is not typically used for queue messaging.  Why would you expose a queue that way?  I see no reason for doing so.  I would not want anyone tunneling through a firewall to read from or write to a queue in a secure zone.  You're thinking about queues in a way that I never do.

Comment: What do the broker logs tell you about the failed send?

Comment: INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/09/01 09:37:16 | com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1   2016/09/01 09:37:16 |  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/09/01 09:37:16 |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/09/01 09:37:16 | Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/09/01 09:37:16 |  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.entrySet(OrderRetainingMap.java:77)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is ok and broker config too, it seems to be a library version problem, can you verify that the jars version used are the same on the client & broker side specially for these one :
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
xstream-1.4.4.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar

Comment: Ya thanks it worked for me by embeding broker into standalone program and starting from there,, as of now http is ok but any help for https ? i created my own Certificate Authority, and generated key store and Trust store - next ?

Comment: to access the broker by https it is simple :
only add these System Properties : 

    `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","client.ks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pwd");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","client.ts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pwd");
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("https://host:port");
 Connection conn = cf.createConnection();`

**important thing, in the broker & client keystores CN must be the hostnames!**

that's it!

Comment: if you have proxy , settings must be done by System Properties too:

   `System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "proxyUser");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "proxyPassword");`

Comment: I think i have problem with certificate/keystore/trustore can u @Hassen guide how to generate cerificate - keystore - truststore for activemq.

Comment: here are the steps needed:
`1-\jdk\bin\keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore broker.ks
\Name LastName ?:serverHost
2-keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker_cert
3-keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.ks
\Name LastName ?:clientHost
4-keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client.ts -file broker_cert
5-keytool -export -alias client -keystore client.ks -file client_cert
6-keytool -import -alias client -keystore broker.ts -file client_cert`

all documentations are here :
http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html

Comment: As per your system.setproperty i acheived SSL protocol, Https is still in progress...can you clarify for HTTPS? @ Hassen

Comment: the provided configuration with System.setProperty works for ssl & https ! you only have to set these system properties and create `new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("https://host:port");`

Comment: Tried with same hostnames(CN) working for SSL but not with HTTPS the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslConnector.getSslContextFactory()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory; when (https://hostname:port) as i am starting broker with programatic embedded broker. any solution for https ?

Comment: The error mentions SslConnector, can you post your broker connectors creation and client code

Comment: <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="https://WSTIN0008:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>

Comment: i dont see the broker connectors creation and client code, can you format the post & verify

Comment: i dont understand how you load the activemq.xml !!

Comment: Currently its starting without activemq.xml. please suggest me any other and simply way to work https protocol.

Comment: can you post broker starting logs. your code works well with https if you add jetty-all.jar and update producer port to 61616.
i ask to verify that you have this connector started because in your code:
you start broker with https at `startBorker("HostName","61616")` and producer connect to `https://HostName:61617. HostName or localhost.`
anyway, your problem here i think is jetty library version, i imagine that you use the same version than `activemq\lib\web\jetty-all-xxx.jar`